# ERROR EN SECUENCIA SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, trigger

Hola estoy aprendiendo SQL, tengo un error que no se porque se genera.

Estoy creando una secuencia para generar ID automáticamente, mi secuencia la hice así:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE   "CAMPANA_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL
```

y tengo un trigger asi:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_CAMPANA"
BEFORE
insert on "CAMPANA"
for each row
begin
IF :NEW.ID_CAMPANA IS NULL THEN 
    SELECT CAMPANA_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID_CAMPANA FROM SYS.DUAL;
END IF;
end;
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago un primer registro se inserta ID 1, al segundo registro ID 2 **pero al tercer registro el ID se convierte en 21**, no sigue la secuencia cuando hago un tercer registro. Pero al cuarto registro si continua en ID 3.

Si alguien me puede explicar o ayudar a solucionar esto por favor... Apenas estoy aprendiendo y hay muchas cosas que desconozco.

Comment: Comentario al margen: No es necesario hacer SELECT-INTO para la secuencia, puedes asignar directamente: `:NEW.ID_CAMPANA := CAMPANA_SEQ.NEXTVAL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras tu secuencia tienes puesto **NOORDER**, debes cambiar a **ORDER** de esta forma garantizas que los valores vayan siempre en orden y de manera secuencial tras el último valor.

Comment: gracias me sirvio tu comentario, pero ahora me estoy dando cuenta que esta iniciando la secuencia a partir del numero que puse en cache, si sigue el correlativo pero desde 20 en adelante. (Porque al cache le puse 20) Que me recomiendas hacer en este casoo?

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta y plantea ahi lo que te sucede de esa forma tendras mas visibilidad